# How to get hidden layer output in tf.estimator.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

For example, I have the following code:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  """Model function for Estimator."""

  first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(features["x"], 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  second_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(first_hidden_layer, 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  output_layer = tf.layers.dense(second_hidden_layer, 1)

  predictions = tf.reshape(output_layer, [-1])

  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)

  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
      learning_rate=params["learning_rate"])
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(
      loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train_op,export_outputs=export_outputs)

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
  x={"x": np.array(training_set.data)},
  y=np.array(training_set.target),
  num_epochs=None,
  shuffle=True)

nn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=100)
```

How can i get the output value of "second_hidden_layer", not the tensor but the real value? I have tried to use this code but failed.

```
export_outputs = {"en_out": tf.estimator.export.RegressionOutput( second_hidden_layer)}
```

Answer (score 0):

[tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) has another parameter called "predictions". Use this dict to return your predictions in direct calls to Estimator.

```
predictions = {
    "en_out" : second_hidden_layer
}
```

and add this to the EstimatorSpec like

```
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode,
    loss=loss,
    train_op=train_op,predictions=predictions)
```

The parameter "export_outputs" is used e.g. for tensorflow serving.